How to Solve p-median with Java CPLEX?
This is an equivalent model to the sample that ships with CPLEX Studio/opl/examples/opl/pmedian, but written in OPL. Here is the equivalent in Java:
import ilog.concert.IloConstraint;
import ilog.concert.IloException;
import ilog.concert.IloLinearNumExpr;
import ilog.concert.IloNumVar;
import ilog.concert.IloRange;
import ilog.cplex.IloCplex;


public class P_Median {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        solveMe();
    }

    public static void solveMe() {

        int p = 2;

        int n = 4; //costumers
        int m = 3; //warehouses
        String[] costumers = {"Albert", "Bob", "Chris", "Daniel"};
        String[] warehouses = {"Santa Clara", "San Jose", "Berkeley"};
        double[] demand = {100.0,   80.0,   80.0,   70.0};
        double[][] distance = { {2.0,   10.0,   50.0},
                                {2.0,   10.0,   52.0}, 
                                {50.0,  60.0,   3.0},
                                {40.0,  60.0,   1.0}};

        double[][]cost = new double [n][m];
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < m; w++) {
                cost[c][w] = demand[c]*distance[c][w];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("cost   = [");
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < m; w++) {
                System.out.print(cost[c][w] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n\r");
        }
        System.out.println("]");

        IloCplex cplex = null;

        try {
            // define new model
            cplex  = new IloCplex();
            //cplex.setParam(IloCplex.Param.Simplex.Display, 0);

            //variables
            IloNumVar[] openWarehouse = new IloNumVar[m];
            for (int w = 0 ; w < m; w++) {
                openWarehouse[w] = cplex.boolVar("openWarehouse"+"_"+w);
            }

            IloNumVar[][] shipToCustomer = new IloNumVar[n][m];
            for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                for (int w = 0; w < m; w++) {
                    shipToCustomer[c][w] = cplex.boolVar("shipToCustomer"+"_"+c+"_"+w);
                }
            }

            //objective
            IloLinearNumExpr objective = cplex.linearNumExpr();
            for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                for (int w = 0; w < m; w++) {
                    objective.addTerm(cost[c][w],shipToCustomer[c][w]);
                }
            }
            cplex.addMinimize(objective);

            // constraints
            IloConstraint[] shipConstraints = new IloConstraint[n];
            IloLinearNumExpr[] shipConstraintExpression = new IloLinearNumExpr[n];
            for (int c=0; c<n; c++) {
                shipConstraintExpression[c] = cplex.linearNumExpr();
                for (int w=0; w<m; w++) {
                    shipConstraintExpression[c].addTerm(1.0, shipToCustomer[c][w]);
                }
                IloRange shipConstraint = cplex.addEq(shipConstraintExpression[c], 1);
                shipConstraint.setName("shipConstraint"+c);
                shipConstraints[c]=shipConstraint;
            }

            IloLinearNumExpr openConstraintExpression = cplex.linearNumExpr();
            for (int w=0; w<m; w++) {
                openConstraintExpression.addTerm(1.0, openWarehouse[w]);
            }
            IloRange openConstraint = cplex.addEq(openConstraintExpression, p);
            openConstraint.setName("openConstraint");

            IloConstraint[][] shipOpenConstraints = new IloConstraint[n][m];
            IloLinearNumExpr[][] shipOpenExpression = new IloLinearNumExpr[n][m];
            for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                for (int w = 0; w < m; w++) {
                    shipOpenExpression[c][w] = cplex.linearNumExpr();
                    shipOpenExpression[c][w].addTerm(1.0, shipToCustomer[c][w]);
                    IloConstraint shipOpenConstraint = cplex.addLe(shipOpenExpression[c][w], openWarehouse[w]);
                    shipOpenConstraint.setName("shipOpenConstraint"+c+w);
                    shipOpenConstraints[c][w]=shipOpenConstraint;
                }
            }

            // solve model
            if (cplex.solve()) {

                System.out.println("\nSolution status = "+ cplex.getStatus()+"\n");
                System.out.println("obj = "+cplex.getObjValue());

                System.out.println("openWarehouse   = [");
                for (int w = 0 ; w < m; w++) {
                    System.out.print(cplex.getValue(openWarehouse[w]) + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println("]");


                System.out.println("shipToCustomer   = [");
                for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                    for (int w = 0; w < m; w++) {
                        System.out.print(cplex.getValue(shipToCustomer[c][w]) + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.print("\n\r");
                }
                System.out.println("]");

                System.out.println("------ ship Constraints -----");
                for (int c=0;c<shipConstraints.length;c++) {
                    System.out.print(((IloRange) shipConstraints[c])+" -> "+"\t");
                    System.out.print("slack constraint "+(c+1)+" = "+cplex.getSlack((IloRange) shipConstraints[c])+"\n");
                }

                System.out.println("------ open Constraint -----");
                System.out.print(((IloRange) openConstraint)+" -> "+"\t");
                System.out.print("slack constraint  = "+cplex.getSlack((IloRange) openConstraint)+"\n");

                System.out.println("------ ship Open Constraints -----");
                for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                    for (int w = 0; w < m; w++) {
                        System.out.print(((IloRange) shipOpenConstraints[c][w])+" -> "+"\t");
                        System.out.print("slack constraint "+(c+1)+""+(w+1)+" = "+cplex.getSlack((IloRange) shipOpenConstraints[c][w])+"\n");
                    }
                }


            } else {
                System.out.println("problem not solved");
            }

        } catch (IloException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(cplex!=null) cplex.end();
        }

    }

}

Can anyone please analyze if this solution is ok?
An integer programming problem is a mathematical optimization or feasibility program in which some or all of the variables are restricted to be integers. In many settings, the term refers to integer linear programming (ILP), in which the objective function and the constraints (other than the integer constraints) are linear.
Integer programming is NP-complete. In particular, the special case of 0-1 integer linear programming, in which unknowns are binary, and only the restrictions must be satisfied, is one of Karp's 21 NP-complete problems.
If some decision variables are not discrete the problem is known as a mixed-integer programming problem.

You can watch a very nice video about pmedian with CPLEX at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUFd0gLTrXk
If I run the OPL model I get
// solution (optimal) with objective 670
670

and I see

in the problem browser.
This can help you check you have the right values.
By the way in java, you do not need to write again your OPL model you can call your OPL model from java.
See examples in CPLEX_Studio2211\opl\examples\opl_interfaces\java
